# bootstrap css for width screens

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a responsive theme in my wordpress site (jax lite theme), with masonry layout. It uses col-md-* classes, by this way, it displays usually 3 columns for laptops and desktop screens, and only one column for mobile devices.

The problem is that in desktop large screens, that 3 columns leave a big space idle around them. I hate webpages that do not use the entire screen space. I want to use col-lg-* or col-md* classes to do this. For example, I want that in a large screens, it displays 4 or 5 columns, or even 3 wider columns too.

I have got this code in template.css:

```html
.post-article .container-fluid .col-md-12,
.post-article .container-fluid .col-md-6,
.post-article .container-fluid .col-md-3 {
 margin-bottom:25px;
}
```

¿How can I do?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this the CSS you are using ? please keep separate your css and bootstrap css.when you are customizing do not use bootstrap and override it .second thing is you should override template, if you want to change the class used on your template html elements if It is bootstarp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .col-lg-4 for larger desktop,if you still facing issue read this
[Bootstrap Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) And also this [Bootstrap grid details](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)
for understanding grids

Comment: I have tried doing exactly that. With lg classes, even with xs classes trying to get more columns in mobile devices. None of that works. Even, I have tried to change all col-md-6, col-md-12 and col-md-4 to col-md-12. It means, the masonry layout only should displays one singular column. It doesn't works! It still displays 3 columns in standard zoom and 1 column in little screens.

Comment: could you please provide me the URL of site so i can analyse it

Answer (score 0):

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options this connection you can help you. You can use multiple classes at the same time.

example

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
`Your Content`
</div>
```